# Puppeteer - How to browse google.com with proxies?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to browse google.com with puppeteer using proxies but Chromium seems to block me.

Code example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const proxyUrl = 'http://gate.smartproxy.com:7000';
    const username = 'xxxxx';
    const password = 'xxxxx';

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [`--proxy-server=${proxyUrl}`],
        headless: false,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.authenticate({ username, password });
    await page.goto('https://google.com/');

    const html = await page.$eval('body', e => e.innerHTML);
    console.log(html);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Error:

```
(node:6673) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED at https://google.com/...
```

I already checked on the proxy side and they are working.

If it's not possible with puppeteer (since they are using Chromium), do you have any alternative ideas on how to browse Google with proxies?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing https with http, and consulting the proxy service and see what documents they have or what advice they can offer. Alternatively, find out what kind of proxy it is and how it normally behaves, and give us more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pluginProxy:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const pluginProxy = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-proxy');
(async() => {
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin()); // Recommende
  puppeteer.use(pluginProxy({
    address: <proxy-host> ,
    port: <proxy-port> ,
    credentials: {
      username: <proxy-user> ,
      password: <proxy-pwd> ,
    }
  }));
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true // Some proxies need it
  });
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com/');

  const html = await page.$eval('body', e => e.innerHTML);
  console.log(html);
  await browser.close();
})();
```